# Count two Columns with two  Where Clauses

Tags: sql, teradata

I know it's just late in the day and my brain is just fried....

Using Teradata, I need to `COUNT DISTINCT` `MEMBERS` that haven't had a `TRANS` in the past six months and also `COUNT` the number of `TRANS` they had historically (prior to the six months). We can just assume the cutoff date to be 01/01/2012. All table is contained in a single table.

For example:

> Member  |  Tran Date
>
> 123  | 01/01/2011
>
> 789   | 06/01/2011
>
> 123 |10/31/2011
>
> 678 | 04/03/2011
>
> 789 | 06/01/2012

So 2 members had a total of 3 transactions dated prior to 1/1/2012 with no transactions later than 1/1/2012.

In this example, my result would be:

> MEMBERS | TRANS
>
> 2 | 3

Comment: What does your table schema look like? Are the `TRANS` values in a different table? We need to know.

Comment: All information is contained in a single table. I think that's part of my problem.

Comment: Can you at least post some sample data? You can simplify it to only the relevant columns if there are a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS MEMBERS,
    COUNT(*) AS TRANS
FROM
    tbl
WHERE 
    member_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT member_id
        FROM tbl
        WHERE trans_date > '2012-01-01'
    )
```

Comment: This might work but I ran out of spool space. The table is huge!

Comment: Perhaps the intermediate result of the join was too large. Try it again with the second solution I just put in. I'm not familiar with Teradata, but depending on how it handles subqueries, it may or may not perform better.

Comment: Second option worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much - not sure I would have figured that out. Thanks again!!

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. I wish MySQL would handle non-correlated subqueries the same way that Teradata seems to!

Comment: I'm not sure that this returns what you want. This will return all members with a transaction prior to 2012-01-01 regardless of their activity between 2012-01-01 and the last time the table was loaded.

Comment: @RobPaller, Yes, I believe you are indeed right about the first query with the `LEFT JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` would have worked if users were linked from another table. However, the second solution with the subquery ***is*** correct and handles Donna's problem well. Thanks for pointing that out — answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one SQL statement. Use subqueries. This is TSQL coz I am unfamiliar with Teradata.

```
DECLARE @CUTOFF DATETIME = DATEADD(MO,-6,GETDATE()) --6MTHS AGO
SELECT COUNT(MEMBERID) AS MEMBERS, SUM(TRANSCOUNT) AS TRANS FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
  MEMBERID, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) TRANSDATE WHERE TRANSDATA.MEMBERID = MEMBER.MEMBERIF) AS TRANSCOUNT
FROM MEMBER WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM TRANSDATA, MEMBER WHERE 
     TRANSDATA.MEMBERID = MEMBER.MEMBERIF 
     AND TRANDATE > @CUTOFF)
)
```

Comment: All in one table? Can't help you without your table schema.

Comment: Thank you for responding - this might have worked but the other response was much more direct. Thanks again!!